# Facebook auth with new optional permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, passport.js, passport-facebook

I am using [passport-facebook](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook) to authenticate a user via facebook. I previously had the scope `[ 'public_profile', 'email' ]`, but recently added `user_friends`.

Now, all the existing users run into an interesting issue... they are forced to grant access to user_friends, unchecking it does not let them continue logging in.

Basically, if you're a new user, you can edit the permissions, `public_profile` being required. You can decline email/user_friends, continue, and never be asked again unless you use `auth-type: "rerequest"`.

However, if an existing user signs in, facebook checks if all of the items in the scope have been requested (in this case `user_friends` has not). It then displays the dialog box with the friends permission, but hides the other 2, since they've already been asked. (see attached image).

Facebook requires the `public_profile` to be checked initially, but because it was already granted, it ends up requiring the `user_friends` permission for the existing users. Seems like this is a bug on facebook's side...

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: What happens when you press "Cancel" - does that result in an error, or does the login flow just continue as normal, and results in an access token with only the previously granted permissions?

Comment: It results in the user cancelling the request and going back to the login page (no access token)

Comment: Then file a bug report. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/